# Using rostopic /image_raw for VideoCapture in OpenCV

Tags: ros, libopencv, image-raw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
All of a sudden, I need to change my approach from calling `TheVideoCapturer.open(0);` (TheVideoCapturer is of a class VideoCapture) to open my internet camera (id 0) to subscribing to published `image_raw` topic. What are the easiest steps here? I'd like to use my TheVideoCapturer object still, because changing everything would be really troublesome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168701/using-rostopic-/image_raw-for-videocapture-in-opencv/) by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

first you must change  your cv::mat image in to ros_image that's possible by [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge) and you can publish it.(for publishing you can use [sensor_msgs::image](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html)or [image_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport))

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0